# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Underscore and parse issues

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, parse-platform

I know there are a bunch of these issues already logged and most seem to be missing %> tags. I'm probably just being blind and missing them

javascript triggered on loading view

```
var positionQuery = new Parse.Query(Position);
            positionQuery.equalTo("user", user);
            positionQuery.find({
                success: function(userPositions){
                this.$el.html(_.template($('#no-position-view').html(), {pos : userPositions}));
                },
                error: function(error){
                    //need an error message here
                    console.log("no positons retrieved");
                }
```

which should be calling the following template

```
    <script type="text/html" id="no-position-view">

    <% if (pos.length > 0){ %>
        <table>
        <thead><th> Company Name </th><th>admin</th><th>date added</th></thead>
        <tbody>
            <% for (var i = 0, i < pos.length, i++){ %>
                <tr class="tableRow"  id='<%= pos[i].objectId %>' >
                    <td><%= pos[i].posCompany %></td>
                    <td><%= pos[i].posAdmin %></td>
                    <td><%= pos[i].createdAt %></td>
                    </tr>

            <% }; %>
        </tbody></table>

    <% } else {%>
        <p> You have no positions setup </p>
    <% } %>                             
 </script>
```

Any ideas

Comment: Uhm .. you have a script tag arround your html .. so It will get parsed as JS not as HTML

Comment: Could you show the generated html?

Comment: It should be generating a table  with three columns, a header row and then the pos fields below

Comment: That's not html .. could you create a jsFiddle showing your problem?

Comment: Not sure if i know how to. Will give it a try

Comment: What does not work in that fiddle?

Comment: having a nightmare [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jviddy/gAEfJ/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a script tag arround your html .. so It will get parsed as Javscript and not as HTML .. and `<table>` for example is not a valid javascript syntax .. So remove the script tag arround it.

I saw the mime-type is set to `text/html`, but maybe your browser does not support it? Try to replace the `<script>` with a `<div>`

Comment: Thanks TobSpr. the HTML in the script tags is the template that underscore should be rendering having looped through the javascript inserting the relevant fields.  I thought the script tags were neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

Change `type` of `script` to `type="text/template"`

```
<script id = "myScript" type="text/template">           
    <% _.each(data, function(res){}); %>
</script>
```